# call jquery function onload and var to php

Tags: php, jquery

This jquery function gives me the **width** when clicking the buttons, but how can instead get the **width** when page loads. I also need the with variable to use in a php file.
How can this b done?

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


<button id="getp">Get Paragraph Width</button>
<button id="getd">Get Document Width</button>
<button id="getw">Get Window Width</button>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<p>
  Sample paragraph to test width
</p>

<script>
function showWidth( ele, w ) {
  $( "div" ).text( "The width for the " + ele + " is " + w + "px." );
}
$( "#getp" ).click(function() {
  showWidth( "paragraph", $( "p" ).width() );
});
$( "#getd" ).click(function() {
  showWidth( "document", $( document ).width() );
});
$("#getw").click(function() {
  showWidth( "window", $( window ).width() );
});
</script>

<?='this does not work '.$_GET['w'];?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can't use the width variable in PHP since it is executed in client side and PHP in the serverside... on page load which width do you want

Comment: Your PHP is executed before your JavaSript even reaches your user's browser.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nQkPt/2/

Comment: ok, but can't the page reload to path tb´he variable to my php once some how?

Comment: Why you need width value in PHP? How you going to use it?

Comment: As  Arun P Johny have said the PHP is been executing in the server side. If you want to comunicate information on the fly from the client side to the server side you need to use things like ajax.

Comment: I need the with to use in php cause I want to include different meue_files depending on the with of the screen

Comment: What you want to include?

Comment: small_menue.php OR large_menue.php depending on the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidtext" name="hidtext" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['length'])) echo  $_GET['length']; ?>"/>


<?php

if(isset($_GET['length']))
{

   if($_GET['length'] > somevalue)
   {
      include('large_menue.php');
   }
   else
   {
      include('small_menue.php');
   }

}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

if( $("#hidtext").val() == "")
{
    $("#hidtext").val($(document).width());
    window.location.replace("thispage.php?length="+$(document).width());
}
</script>
```

Explanation:

Once you open `thispage.php` it get document length and redirects the page to same page by attaching url parameter.
if the url parameter `length` is set then its value is stored in `hidtext`.
If `hidtext` has value then page does not find width and reloads its.

as the url parameter has the value of document width you can check it and inculde appropriate file

Comment: Thanks, but then I need to submit a form or something to get the "hidtext"-value to my PHP. Isn't there a way to get it to a PHP vaiable directly?

Comment: no i have stored the value in url parameter , so you dont want to submit the form for getting length

Comment: read my explanation and try to implement it, if you still have query post it, i will try to clear it

Comment: can you please be more specific where you are not getting ?

Comment: Sorry! None of my files shows up. I guess I cant post the code in this box, but I'll try. Tried to echo text instead as well.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hidtext" name="hidtext" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['length'])) echo  $_GET['length']; ?>"/>
<script>
function showWidth( ele, w ) {if( $("#hidtext").val() == "")
{
$("#hidtext").val($(document).width());
window.location.replace("test2.php?length="+$(document).width());
}
</script>
<?if(isset($_GET['length'])){if($_GET['length'] > 600 ){echo 'big';}else{echo 'small';}}?>

Comment: dont write my jquery codes inside  `function showWidth( ele, w )`, instead just write them in plain between `script` tags

Comment: You are not getting any o/p because you write all things inside a function and you are not calling that function, so the page remains as it it

Comment: Yes, that works, but the page loops continuously, but I guess I can kill that with a PHP-check, unless you don't have a better idea :)

<script>
function showWidth( ele, w ) {if( $("#hidtext").val() == ""){}
</script>

<script>
$("#hidtext").val($(document).width());
window.location.replace("test2.php?length="+$(document).width());
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following structure;

```
<script>
    var w = '400';
</script>
<?php $w = "<script>document.write(w)</script>"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Anyway, add this script

```
 <script>

     function showWidth( ele, w ) {
          $( "div" ).text( "The width for the " + ele + " is " + w + "px." );


         window.location =window.location + '?w='+w;
     }

 </script>
```

Use `$.ajax` to send data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe incorrect and unnessessary code that I don't understnad, but this work. :)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<button id="getw" style="visibility:hidden;"></button>



<?if(!$_REQUEST['width_checked']) {?>

<script>
     function showWidth( ele, w ) {
         window.location =window.location + '?width_checked=1&w='+w;
    }

    $("#getw").click(function () {
    showWidth("window", $(window).width());

    $('body').load('', function () {});
    }).click(); //show the window width on page load
</script>
 <?}?>

</body>
</html>
```